# Is it possible to programmatically power on/off the 3V3?

Tags: netduino

I have a Netduino Plus with at transeiver attached via SPI. I would like to reset the transiever every time the Netduino restarts. Is it possible to programmatically power on/off the 3V3 pin?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a FET (controlled by one of the I/O) pins to enable/disable 3V3 power to your transceiver.  When you say transceiver, I think "more than a few mA" :)

BTW, we took this feedback into account with the new Shield Base module for Netduino Go.  It has an integrated FET on both 3V3 and 5V power headers, so you could enable/disable power to your shield in code.  Once the new Ethernet go!bus module ships and the Shield Base comes out of beta (soon), your solution can be redeployed to Netduino Go + Shield Base with few/no code changes.

Chris
Secret Labs LLC

Comment: Freetronics sells a board with four mosfets, support circuitry and screw terminals for $10 if you decide to go with Chris' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the circuit diagram ( http://www.netduino.com/netduinoplus/schematic.pdf ), I can see only the Micro SD Card Slot having its power controlled programmatically. You could rig up a relay to control it (via a transistor, of course) instead, or if the transceiver uses less than 130mA (the current limit of the device shown: http://www.datasheetarchive.com/BSS84W-7-F-datasheet.html) you could copy the circuit from the Netduino Plus. Buying a relay shield looks like overkill, but you might have other uses for it.

Have you looked into resetting the transceiver programmatically instead of the brute-force method of power-cycling it?

Comment: Power-cycling is absolutely reliable. Software reset is not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another view. You could use a transistor powered off the netduino RESET line, this will reset the device every time the netduino reboots. Or you can just link the transistor to a spare digital pin and power it in code..

Answer (score 0):

What specific SPI device are you using?  You mention that it's a transceiver but we could probably provide better information if we know the exact part number.  If your device requires less than 8mA the [Netduino Plus specs](http://www.netduino.com/netduinoplus/specs.htm) seem to indicate that one option could be using a digital output pin as the power source.

Unfortunately Secret Labs don't use exactly the language I'd expect and call out the sink and source current maximums so I would contact them directly first to see if you risk blowing your chip.  I'll see if I can get an answer from them and amend this post if/when I do.

Update: Sink and source current is the same on the Netduino.  See [my post on their forums about sink vs. source current](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/4033-sinksource-current-maximums/) for a more in depth explanation.  So, if your device can run off of just a few milliamps you should be able to use a digital I/O pin to power it.

Also, a lot of devices have enable pins.  You can usually reset them with that line instead of pulling the power if that helps.  Sometimes with flaky hardware it is better to pull the power though.